# PHP - CRON, Schedule a php script to run on every dynamic schedule for push notification

Tags: php, redis, cron

I Have a list of appointments at 9am, 9:15am, 10am, The appointment is scheduled dynamically.  I have to send the push notification for the time scheduled.

- As the scheduled time is dynamic or editable by HR.
- I 'm running a cron for every one minute, if i find the time scheduled falls under , the cron is running like every one minute.

Please suggest a plan for the execution, because i don't find this as a best solution.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you're following is correct. Since the appointment is scheduled dynamically, it can be at any time. Run the cron every minute and in your script check if there are any appointments whose schedule time has arrived and which has notification sent to false. Trigger notifications for those appointments and set the notification sent to true on them.

Comment: As Neil Richins said, we can create a crontab itself while scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

Editing crontab directly from PHP

One trick I use on resource limited systems is to edit the crontab itself in stead of constantly calling a PHP script every 60 seconds. 
Converting your crontab to a PHP array makes easy work of scheduling tasks.

Adding tasks may be accomplished using array_push

```
<?PHP
$newcron='00 09 * * * /usr/bin/PHP /fullPath/myPhpScript.php';    // New time and task         
$crons= explode( PHP_EOL ,shell_exec('crontab -l')); 
array_push($crons,$newcron);
file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', implode (PHP_EOL,$crons));
echo exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');
?>
```

Removing tasks may be accomplished using unset

```
<?PHP
$crons= explode( PHP_EOL ,shell_exec('crontab -l')); 
unset($crons[1]);                                       //Task entry to remove
file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', implode (PHP_EOL,$crons));
echo exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');
?>
```

The Crontab format is:

```
* * * * *    /usr/bin/php /fullPath/myPhpScript.php
| | | | |    | 
| | | | |    +-- Command to call your script             
| | | | +---- Day of the Week   (range: 1-7, 1 standing for Monday)
| | | +------ Month of the Year (range: 1-12)
| | +-------- Day of the Month  (range: 1-31)
| +---------- Hour              (range: 0-23)
+------------ Minute            (range: 0-59)
```

If your appointments are at 9:00, 9:15, and 10:00 am you could start with a crontab as similar to the one below.

```
00 09 * * * /usr/bin/PHP /fullPath/0900PushNotifyList.php
15 09 * * * /usr/bin/PHP /fullPath/0915PushNotifyList.php
00 10 * * * /usr/bin/PHP /fullPath/1000PushNotifyList.php
```

More information about the crontab command and format may be found at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info

Comment: That's a great idea @Neil Richnis , Create a file dynamically as soon as the appointments placed. Well explained.